# AngularJS directive, scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

hey I have a question

If in directive I use scope {}. Then I know that is create local scope. but could someone tell me how it looks. Because I have a problem with understanding it.

1. It is so that If i add dom attribute, for example card

   `<div modal-window-card card="card" ng-model="text"></div>`

Then whole variable with $scope.card is assigned to this card where next, I can modificate everything in the directive like in function yes?

2. But why I can't write all value from variable in :

   ```
   link: function(card) {
   console.log(card)
   ```

   },
3. And one more thing, whole directive is like in new local scope yes? I mean, all functions, which are located in the directive is in this scope yes?

for example

```
<buton ng-click="fefe()">start</buton>
```

If i click start buton it will execute function with the directive, yes? if i set `ng-click="$parent.fefe()"` then after click it will execute function with parent scope, yes?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `link` incorrectly. The signature is `link(scope, element, attrs)`. As for the other questions, yes and yes, assuming your `buton` is within the directive's template.